# How to change options of select box based on another select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php page in which i used 2 select box one is to choose vehicle (vehicle is RV , Campervans and cars) and second one is no. of passengers. What is want is when i select Rv from first box then no. of passengers is 8 and when i select campervans then no. of passengers is 5. I have code which works fine but after hit search it shows 5 no. of passengers for both rv and campervans..

Please check code below

```
<div class="fields">
<p>Vehicle Type</p>
<select class="car" name="car_type" id="car_type">
<option value="0">Select Vehicle</option>
    <?php if(count($vehicleType) > 0 ){
        foreach($vehicleType as $vt){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $vt ?>" <?=isset($_GET['car_type'])&&$_GET['car_type']==$vt?'selected':'';?> ><?php echo $vt ?></option>
    <?php   }

    } ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="fields">
<?php
$number_of_passengers = 8;
if(!empty($_REQUEST['car_type'])) {
$number_of_passengers = $_REQUEST['car_type'] == 'Campervans' ? 5 : 8;
}

$passengers = 0;
if(!empty($_REQUEST['passengers'])){
$passengers = (int) $_REQUEST['passengers'];
}
?>

<select class="half" name="passengers" id="passengers">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_passengers; $i++) {
?>
<option
        <?php
            if($i == $passengers) {
                echo ' selected ';
            }
        ?>
        >
        <?php echo $i ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
?>
 </select>

</div>

<script>
$('#car_type').change(function() {

    $("#passengers").children().removeAttr("selected");

    if ($(this).val() === 'Campervans') {
        $('#passengers option:nth-child(n+5)').hide();
    } else {
        $('#passengers option').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: why do you need to show the number of passenger inside a `select` tag? do you want the user to have the ability to change the number of passenger or will you set it yourself on server side?

Comment: only want to set it myself on server side.It works good but when problem is only after hitting search

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gxlvvr   http://prntscr.com/gxlw17 see these are the screenshots when i select values from first select box

Comment: how do you validate the data on the `search` function?

Comment: as this page is connecting to database so it shows result by the values in database

Comment: so what you mean is you want to update the `select` tag for passenger after you click on the `select` tag of `car type`?

Comment: Yes exactly..............